# Changing the child's local matrix so as to offset the scaling of the parent local matrix

Tags: unity-game-engine, math, matrix, opengl, geometry

A <-- B <-- C - are chain of local matrices.

If I scale the `localA`, it also affects to the `worldB`. I want to `warldB` stays unscaled.

The problem is that I can only edit the `localB` matrix and **nothing else**. Thus, 'localB' must be "unscaled" before its world coordinate calculated.

Pseudocode

```
scale = 1 to 5

localA = mat4.idt() * R(Y, 45) * S(1, scale, scale) * T(0, 0, 0)
localB = mat4.idt() * R(Y, 45) * S(1, 1, 1) * T(1, 0, 0) // I can only edit this
localC = mat4.idt() * R(Y, 45) * S(1, 1, 1) * T(1, 0, 0)

worldA = localA
worldB = worldA * localB
worldC = worldB * localC
```

Rest state. No extra scaling, just local to world conversion

[image]

`localA` scaled and it scales children

[image]

And this is what I want it to look like

[image]

Comment: `S(1 / scale, 1 / scale, 1 / scale)` and `T(1 / scale, 0, 0)` ?

Comment: @derHugo Hi, It only worked for me when I removed the rotation at all and set the scale to [1, 1/scale, 1/scale]. But with rotation, the result becomes disproportionate, as in the second pic. The cube is shearing or something.

Comment: You could always invert the rotation, invert the scale, re-do the rotation: R(Y, -45) * S(1, 1/scale, 1/scale) * R(Y, 45); but perhaps there's a more efficient way